# Sum of elements in the stack using push and pop

Tags: assembly, sum

My program doesn't work, i want to sum elements which are in the stack.
I puched the numbers in the stack and than i want to sum them by restoring them from the stack and stuck the result in the eax register.

```
.code32

#######################################
.data
msgFin:   .string "\n-----\n"
sizeMsg = . - msgFin

msgA: .string "addition\n"
sizemsgA = . - msgA

number:   .long 0

#######################################
.bss

#######################################
.text

.global _start

_start:   
andl $0, %eax

initialisePile:
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp

empile:
movl $1, %edx
push %edx
movl $2, %edx
push %edx
movl $3, %edx
push %edx
movl $4, %edx
push %edx
movl $5, %edx
push %edx

showAddition:
movl $msgA, %ecx 
movl $4, %eax 
movl $1, %ebx 
movl $sizemsgA,%edx 
int $0x80

additionStack:
pop %edx
addl %edx,%eax
cmpl %esp,%ebp
je exit
jmp additionStack

exit:
movl $4, %eax 
movl $1, %ebx 
movl $msgFin,%ecx  
movl $sizeMsg,%edx 
int $0x80

show result:
movl %eax,$number
movl $number,%ecx
movl $4, %eax 
movl $1, %ebx 
int $0x80

exit2:
movl $0, %ebx   
movl $1, %eax  
int $0x80
```

I don't know why my program don't show the result of the sum of elements in the stuck.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Have you mentally followed the flow of your program? It seems wrong to me. Can you explain each block so we can better understand it?

Comment: You can simplify with `push $1`.  You don't have to mov into EDX first.  And instead of `je exit` / `jmp top_of_loop`, you can just `jne top_of_loop` to make a normal `do{}while()` style asm loop.

Comment: Apart from probably not getting the expected result of 15 = 0FH because accumulator isn't cleared before additionStack, the binary value in %eax needs to be converted to an ASCII string.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why my program don't show the result of the sum of elements in the stuck.

A number of reasons:

- You empty the accumulator `%eax` too early in the code! Your `andl $0, %eax` instruction should come right before the loop where you actually do the additions. Like you have written it, the register was used for something else in the mean time. (The call to show the first message `movl $4, %eax`).
- You loose the result of the addition because the `%eax` register gets corrupted by the call to display the second message! The `movl %eax,$number` instruction belongs directly beneath the addition loop.
- To show the resulting number you've used the same api function that you used to display the text messages. The `%ecx` register holds an address and `%edx` holds a size.
  But this code:

  ```
  show result:
  movl %eax,$number    <- Binary form
  movl $number,%ecx
  movl $4, %eax 
  movl $1, %ebx 
  int $0x80
  ```

  does not put the address of the textual representation of the result in `%ecx` nor does it define the size `%edx`. The `movl %eax,$number` instruction only stores the binary representation of the result.
  *Either use an api function that is able to output a numerical value or convert the number into text yourself.*

---

Your code with a few corrections added:

```
_start:   

initialisePile:
  push %ebp
  movl %esp, %ebp

empile:
  push $1
  push $2
  push $3
  push $4
  push $5

showAddition:
  movl $msgA, %ecx 
  movl $4, %eax 
  movl $1, %ebx 
  movl $sizemsgA,%edx 
  int  $0x80

  xorl %eax, %eax    ; better than 'andl $0, %eax'
additionStack:
  pop  %edx
  addl %edx,%eax
  cmpl %esp,%ebp
  jne  additionStack
  movl %eax,$number  ; don't loose the sum

exit:
  movl $4, %eax 
  movl $1, %ebx 
  movl $msgFin,%ecx  
  movl $sizeMsg,%edx 
  int  $0x80

; Here you decide how you want to show the n u m b e r!
```